# How do I add a flat rate?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have installed the following modules in an existing Drupal site.

- Commerce and Commerce UI
- Customer and Customer UI
- Price
- Line Item and Line Item UI
- Order and Order UI
- Checkout, Payment, Product
- Product Reference
- Cart and Product Pricing
- Tax
- Product UI
- Tax UI
- Payment UI
- Shipping
- Shipping Flat Rate

The shop is working fine as expected.

I'm trying to set up different shipping rates, so I'm following the instructions on the project page for the [Flat Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) module. However, when I go to *Store > Configuration > Shipping* there is no option to add a flat rate service.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *Store > Configuration > Shipping* there are few tabs like *Shipping services* and *Shipping methods*; below them, there is another set of tabs which include *Flat rate*. That should be chosen before the *Add a flat rate service* link becomes visible on that page.